# Is it appropriate to name a class Controller when I am not using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, naming-conventions

I have several classes that facilitate CRUD, perform queries and act as single starting point for executing commands in my domain.  Typically I will use the Controller class in Code-behind such as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var customerController = new CustomerController();
   customerList.DataSource = customerController.GetAllCustomers();
}
```

Is there a more appropriate name that I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

Looks like your `CustomerController` is a kind of `Repository`.

So i suggest the name `CustomerRepository`

> Use a repository to separate the logic that retrieves the data and maps it to the entity model from the business logic that acts on the model.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - The Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Comment: Makes good sense.  In fact I do use the repository pattern.  What I am trying to achieve is class that is the starting point for all operations in my domain.  Would this be a facade, a proxy?

Comment: I need more informations to help. What you mean exactly with "starting point".

Comment: @garcon1986 I think not enough information to suggest `CustomerService`. `CustomerRepository` should be right or at least not wrong. Not?

Comment: I don't know the structure of his project, neither if there are  different layers. If it doesn't, CustomerRepository can be a name. :)